Trouble Populating Google Sheet Column with CVE Descriptions - CVE ID Undefined
I'm trying to use Google Apps Script to populate column D of my Google Sheet with the corresponding CVE description based on the CVE ID from column A. I'm getting the CVE descriptions/summary from the https://cve.circl.lu API. However, when I run my script, I encounter an issue where cveID is undefined, and it appears the function to populate the summaries (populateCveSummaries()) is not being called correctly.
Here's my current script:
function getCveSummary(cveID) {
  var apiUrl = 'https://cve.circl.lu/api/cve/' + cveID;
  try {
    Logger.log('Fetching CVE summary for: ' + cveID);  // Log the CVE ID
    var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(apiUrl);  // Fetch data from the API
    var json = JSON.parse(response.getContentText());  // Parse the JSON response
    
    Logger.log('CVE ID used in API call: ' + cveID);  // Log the CVE ID for debugging
    
    // Check if summary exists, otherwise return a default message
    if (json && json.summary) {
      return json.summary;
    } else {
      return 'No summary available for this CVE';
    }
  } catch (e) {
    Logger.log('Error fetching CVE summary for: ' + cveID);  // Log the error
    return 'Error fetching CVE summary';  // Error handling
  }
}

function populateCveSummaries() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  
  var dataRange = sheet.getRange('A2:A');  // CVE IDs in column A starting from A2
  var data = dataRange.getValues();  // Get the values (CVE IDs) from column A

  Logger.log('Data retrieved from Column A: ' + JSON.stringify(data));  // Log the raw data from column A
  
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    var cveID = data[i][0];  // Extract each CVE ID from the 2D array
    
    Logger.log('Processing row ' + (i + 2) + ' - CVE ID: ' + cveID);  // Log which row is being processed
    
    if (cveID && cveID.trim() !== "") {
      var summary = getCveSummary(cveID);  // Fetch the summary for the CVE
      Logger.log('Summary fetched for ' + cveID + ': ' + summary);  // Log the fetched summary

      sheet.getRange(i + 2, 4).setValue(summary);  // Set the summary in column D (index 4)
      Logger.log('Setting summary for row ' + (i + 2) + ': ' + summary);  // Log cell update
    } else {
      Logger.log('No valid CVE ID found in row ' + (i + 2));  // Log if no CVE ID is found in a row
    }
  }
}

When I execute the script, cveID seems to be undefined as shown in the execution log. Here's the relevant portion of my execution log:
Execution log
11:28:23 AM    Notice    Execution started
11:28:23 AM    Info    Fetching CVE summary for: undefined
11:28:23 AM    Info    CVE ID used in API call: undefined
11:28:24 AM    Notice    Execution completed

It seems like populateCveSummaries() isn't working as expected, and cveID isn't getting populated with the values from column A. As a result, I can't fetch the CVE summary correctly.
My Environment
I'm using Google Sheets Apps Script.
The CVE IDs are in column A starting from cell A2.
I'm fetching CVE summaries using the public API from https://cve.circl.lu/api/cve/.
Screenshots - Google Sheets, Circl:

What I've Tried
◉I used Logger.log() to debug, and it appears cveID is undefined.
◉The function populateCveSummaries() doesn't seem to be called properly or isn't looping through the data as expected.
What I Need Help With
◉Why is cveID coming up as undefined even though the values are present in column A?
◉How can I ensure that the function populateCveSummaries() loops through each row and fetches the data correctly?
◉Any suggestions on how to properly set up the data variable or change the range to get the correct values?
◉How can I trigger the script automatically whenever a value is entered into column A?
Google Sheets Structure
The structure of the Google Sheet is:
Column A: CVE (e.g., CVE-2021-24499)
Column B: Rules Triggered
Column C: Category
Column D: CVE Description (the column I want to populate)
Column E: Reference
Column F: Comments
I'm new to coding, and any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you in advance!

When I execute the script, cveID seems to be ... What do you mean by "When I execute..."? How are you executing? Describe the steps by [edit]ing your question.

What about the logs in populateCveSummaries? What do they output?

I think TheMaster and myself are sensing that you may be manually running getCveSummary directly, in which case, without any arguments, the parameter cveID is of course undefined. Please confirm whether this is the case.

You should run the populateCveSummaries() function and not the getCveSummary(cveID) function.
To avoid trouble, make getCveSummary(cveID) private by renaming it to getCveSummary_(cveID). A private function cannot be accidentally run in the script editor.
Then try this shorter code:
function populateCveSummaries() {
  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  const idRange = sheet.getRange('A2:A');
  const targetRange = idRange.offset(0, 3);
  const ids = idRange.getValues().flat();
  const result = ids.map(getCveSummary_);
  const table = result.map(row => [row]);
  targetRange.setValues(table);
}

The shorter version should be easier to debug, and it will run much more efficiently because it uses batch operations.

Hey @doubleunary, I just wanted to thank you for your help! Your solution worked perfectly, and my script is now auto-populating the CVE descriptions exactly as I needed. :D
Thanks again!

See how to accept @PraveenKS
